# Autofill one column based on the time interval in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following is the data that I am having

```
timediff                      text
2018-06-19 01:00:00            A
2018-06-19 01:00:01 
2018-06-19 01:00:02 
2018-06-19 01:00:03 
2018-06-19 02:00:00 
2018-06-19 02:00:01            B
2018-06-19 02:00:02 
2018-06-19 02:00:03 
2018-06-19 02:15:00 
2018-06-19 02:15:01 
2018-06-19 02:15:02            
2018-06-19 02:15:03            C
2018-06-19 02:30:00 
2018-06-19 02:30:01 
2018-06-19 02:30:02 
2018-06-19 02:30:03            D
```

I want to fill the text based on the timediff column. If the timediff is within 1-5 seconds, I want it to be filled with the text. For eg, if the timediff for the first four entries are within 4-5 seconds, I would need the text to be filled with "A". Similarly, I want all the other rows to filled. The output be like,

```
timediff                      text
2018-06-19 01:00:00            A
2018-06-19 01:00:01            A    
2018-06-19 01:00:02            A    
2018-06-19 01:00:03            A    
2018-06-19 02:00:00            B    
2018-06-19 02:00:01            B
2018-06-19 02:00:02            B    
2018-06-19 02:00:03            B    
2018-06-19 02:15:00            C    
2018-06-19 02:15:01            C    
2018-06-19 02:15:02            C               
2018-06-19 02:15:03            C
2018-06-19 02:30:00            D    
2018-06-19 02:30:01            D    
2018-06-19 02:30:02            D    
2018-06-19 02:30:03            D
```

Since these are all within few seconds, I want to populate the column based on it.

I tried to take the time difference on both the directions and tried backfill or frontfill option, but it didnt work for me.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: How is your data stored? Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes Pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your data looks like besides what you posted so I had to make some assumptions (line making blank values equal to '' and converting your datetimes strings to datetimes). This should get you on the right track:

```
dat = [
    ['2018-06-19 01:00:00', 'A'],
    ['2018-06-19 01:00:01', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 01:00:02', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 01:00:03', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:00:00', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:00:01', 'B'],
    ['2018-06-19 02:00:02', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:00:03', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:15:00', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:15:01', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:15:02',  ''],          
    ['2018-06-19 02:15:03', 'C'],
    ['2018-06-19 02:30:00', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:30:01', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:30:02', ''],
    ['2018-06-19 02:30:03', 'D']]

df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=['timediff', 'text'])

df['timediff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timediff'])

dff = df[df['text'] != '']

df['text_new'] = df.apply(lambda dr: dff['text'][(dff['timediff']-dr['timediff']).abs().argmin()], axis=1)
```

Alternatively for large amounts of data, the following should be faster (though not as elegant).

```
# Use same code as above before we define dff.
dff = df[df['text'] != ''].copy() # Making a copy is safer here

df['text_new'] = ''

j = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    while dff.iloc[j+1]['timediff'] < df.loc[i,'timediff']:
        j += 1
    df.loc[i,'text_new'] = dff.loc[(dff.iloc[j:j+2]['timediff']-df.loc[i,'timediff']).abs().idxmin()]['text']
```

resulting df:

```
              timediff text text_new
0  2018-06-19 01:00:00    A        A
1  2018-06-19 01:00:01             A
2  2018-06-19 01:00:02             A
3  2018-06-19 01:00:03             A
4  2018-06-19 02:00:00             B
5  2018-06-19 02:00:01    B        B
6  2018-06-19 02:00:02             B
7  2018-06-19 02:00:03             B
8  2018-06-19 02:15:00             C
9  2018-06-19 02:15:01             C
10 2018-06-19 02:15:02             C
11 2018-06-19 02:15:03    C        C
12 2018-06-19 02:30:00             D
13 2018-06-19 02:30:01             D
14 2018-06-19 02:30:02             D
15 2018-06-19 02:30:03    D        D
```

Comment: Does this check M * N iterations for the data ? I feel it is taking a lot of time to show even sample data ? I am running for 1 entry for the filtered dff dataframe against the original df dataframe which has 20K entries and its been more than 5 minutes and its still running ?

Comment: It does indeed. There are probably faster ways to do it but it would require more details about the nature of the gaps. My answer addresses your question but if you like to re-word your question I would be happy to take a look. For instance, what is the number of filled text vs empty?

Comment: @haimen try the alternative I just added to the answer with your large dataset. It's not as pretty but it should result in less computations. For small datasets, my original answer should still be better. If this answers your question, please kindly accept this answer.